# Thunderbird: How to send a mail to all receivers of a folder

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

does anybody know a way to copy all the the receivers of a specific (sent) folder in thunderbird? I want to send an email to all of those receivers. I tried FiltaQuilla Addon, but unfourtunatey it can only add all the FROM-adresses to a list in the adressbook. The "FROM" is always me, this doens't work out for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting the question I remebered the plugin "ImportExportTools" and found the new version "ImportExportTools NG". With this addon I can export a complete folder as CSV file (second csv option), open the file with Libre Office Calc, select the whole column "receiver", copy it and paste it to the BCC field of a new email. Not the nicest way, but it works.